# Calculating the volume of a solid with a double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

[image: The triangle from the question is in the Geogebra Graph here]The solid lies under the hyperboloid $z = xy$ and above the triangle in the $xy-$plane with vertices $(1, 2),(1, 4),$ and $(5, 2)$. Find the volume of the given solid.

This is the work I have done so far:

$\int\limits_1^5\int\limits_1^b f(x,y) dydx$

where $b=-0.5x+4.5$

and $f(x,y)=xy$

This gives me the answer of $42$, while the correct answer is $24$. I believe my error is in the bounds of the integral, but I can't figure out where it is. Can someone tell me what the error is with my integral?

Comment: $f(x,y)$ instead of $f(x)$. Is not it ?

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Yes I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Under $\int$ too :)

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Thanks got that one as well! :)

Comment: You could suggest a drawing at least of the triangle, right? (with geogebra)

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Added a picture of the triangle.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen For this one, I think it would be dydx though? I'm integrating over dy first then dx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first obtain $\int_{2}^{4.5-0.5x}ydy=\frac{16.25-4.5x+0.25x^2-4}{2}$

Then $\int_{1}^{5}\frac{16.25x-4.5x^2+0.25x^3-4x}{2}dx=24.$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the integral being evaluated over y.

$\int\limits_1^5 \int\limits_2^b f(x,y) \, dydx$

Comment: I got it : $24$ :)

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Accepted it! :)